# Functions that share names with methods

Tags: python, naming-conventions, pep8

Is it a bad idea to declare a function that has the same name as a method?

In this example set has the method **union** and I have also declared a function called **union**:

```
def union(*lists):
    '''returns a list containing all unique values from input lists'''

    if len(lists) == 0:
        return lists[0]

    result = lists[0]
    for item in range(1, len(lists)):
        result = set(result).union(set(lists[item]))

    return list(result)    

a=[1,2,4]
b=[4,5,1]
c=[9,7,5]

print union(a, b, c)
```

I looked at PEP8 and found that [methods and functions have the same naming rules](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables), but is it OK to give them the same name?

Comment: Unless it doesn't get yourself (or your team members) confused, it is ok.

Comment: Thanks. I was checking to see if there were any best practices that I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem using names that also are used as methods on some objects. Different namespaces won't conflict.

The only thing you need to worry about are masking names in the *same* namespace; built-ins are global, globals are visible in the local namespace, so you don't want to mask built-in names.

But methods on an object are only visible to that scope; you need to qualify the method with `someset.union()`, which can never conflict with your `union()` function.

If you did have to restrict your names to anything that is not already taken by a method in the Python standard library, you would have scarcely have any names left to use.